# Как в Thymeleaf выводить двухмерный массив?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Допустим, есть двухмерный массив:

```
String m[][]={
    {"1x1","1x2","1x3","1x4"},
    {"2x1","2x2","2x3","2x4"},
    {"3x1","3x2","3x3","3x4"},
    {"4x1","4x2","4x3","4x4"}
};
```

***(Массив может быть разной "длины" и "высоты")***

В классе, где я передаю контент я пишу:

```
context.setVariable("m", m);
```

Как записать данный массив в Thymeleaf? Я пробовал реализовать вот таким способом, но у меня не получилось:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>


<div th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0,${#arrays.length(m)},1)}">
    <div th:each="j : ${#numbers.sequence(0,${#arrays.length(m[1])},1)}">
        <span th:text="${m[i][j]}"></span>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если ты передаёшь переменную в контекст следующим образом:
`context.setVariable("arrayNumber", m);`
То в шаблоне ты должен обращаться к `arrayNumber`, а не к m

Comment: @АлександрКосарев я имел ввиду ("m", arrayNumber)

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iterable-values) в качестве значения `th:each` может использоваться массив, соответственно, должен работать следующий код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:each="i : ${m}">
        <div th:each="j : ${i}">
            <span th:text="${j}"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```